# How to change more than one string variables to integer and minus 1?

Tags: ruby

I want to change 8 strings to integer type and minus 1. I wrote the code as:

```
foo1, foo2, too3 ... = foo1.to_i - 1, foo2.to_i - 1, foo3.to_i -1, ...
```

But I think it's too complex. Are there some better ways to achieve this goal?

Comment: @jdoe Not really... Questions can already have tags. It's redundant at best.

Comment: @jdoe Thanks, I want it to be more obvious..

Comment: But I think the problem can be more obvious by this way, isn't it?

Comment: @Tony http://cl.ly/image/0l113b2Z2F1e It says "ruby" 3 times in that tiny little image. How obvious do you need it to be?

Comment: You succeeded and got my attention.

Comment: @AlexWayne All right..I removed the ruby-on-rails tag, I overcome the problem in my rails project, but it doesn't matter to the rails..

Comment: it really has to be an in-place operation? (it's usually a bad idea). They are not even the same type...

Comment: @tokland Not necessarily

Comment: Do you have to keep all these values in different locals? The fact that you are applying the same operation to all of them suggests there may be some connection between them, and it might be reasonable to keep them all in some kind of data structure. Then it would be much easier to make the code you show here more concise.

Comment: @AlexD Yes,you are right thanks you~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting them in an Array would be the simplest thing.

```
%w{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 }.map!(&:to_i).map!(&:pred)
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[:foo1, :foo2, ... etc. ...].each { |foo| eval "#{foo} = #{foo}.to_i - 1" }
```

Although it's a bad idea if you've decided to do it.

Comment: @AlexD Fixed! I was blinded by the former title :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use this, eval is dangerous and dynamic.  I would recommend moving your values into a hash where you can control the keys.  If you want to do literally what you asked:

```
(1..2).map {|n | eval("foo#{n}").to_i - 1}
```

Example:

```
> foo1 = 2
=> 2
> foo2 = 3
=> 3
> (1..2).map {|n | eval("foo#{n}").to_i - 1}
=> [1, 2]
```

... non-terrifying way to store/process these values:

```
> hash = { :foo1 => 2, :foo2 => 3 }
=> {:foo1=>2, :foo2=>3}
hash.keys.inject({}) { |h, key| h[key] = hash[key].to_i - 1; h }
=> {:foo1=>1, :foo2=>2}
```

Comment: You misunderstood me.. foo1, foo2 just mean the name of the argument, they may be `anyletters = "123", another = "456"`,

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with 8 variables and need to do the same operation on them it usually means that they are linked somehow and can be grouped, for example in a hash:

```
data = {:foo1 => "1", :foo2 => "2", ...}
data2 = Hash[data.map { |key, value| [key, value.to_i - 1] }]
```

Note that instead of updating inplace values I create a new object, a functional approach is usually more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to @Winfields solution this might be enough:

```
foo1 = "123"
foo2 = "222"
too3 = "0"
def one_less_int(*args) # the splat sign (#) puts all arguments in an array
 args.map{|str| str.to_i-1}
end
p one_less_int(foo1, foo2, too3) #=> [122, 221, -1]
```

But putting everything in an array beforehand, as others are suggesting, is more explicit.